# How to make music slider, start time and end time?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make music slider like this:
[slider image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRX3c.jpg)
I am new to dart so please forgive any mistakes in the question.
I am just confused on how to set the time elapsed playing and total time.

my code:

```
double sliderValue = 0;
  Duration max = const Duration(seconds: 120);

Row(
            children: [
              Text('${sliderValue.toInt()}'),
              Slider(
                  value: sliderValue,
                  min: 0,
                  max: max.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                  onChanged: (double value){
                    setState(() {
                      sliderValue = value;
                    });
                  }
              ),
              Text('${max.inMinutes}')
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to manually implement it. You can do this by first getting the audio length from the metadata of the file. Once you get that, you can show the current progress based on the total.

Another way is to check out [this](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_video_progress_bar) package. Also, you might be using the audio player package. It also has a callback to get the current position of the audio. Check it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers#:%7E:text=setState(()%20%3D%3E%20duration%20%3D%20d)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B-,Position%20Event,-This%20Event%20updates).